# Window Service status it is appearing as running, But not working

Tags: c#, web-services, service, window

I am not quite sure, if I can have an answer to this question but it will be nice to know some suggestions about it.

I have a windows service with two threads. It was working perfectly fine for a time but it seems that it stopped working on last week. When I checked the service status it is appearing as running and startup type is automatic. But service didn't pick the data from service queue. There is no error log and I think thread got stopped, but don't why?

Comment: Try checking the Application log in Event Viewer.

Comment: I'm having the same situation. Did u find a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I have a similar issue. Be great to get your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We found while deployment of Application , there was some dependecy of service on windows, which cause these issue.
We fixed the issue by each time reset the IIS and stop all services and then reinstall them each time.

Comment: Restarting/Reinstalling service is a very crude work around. Hoping for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In our case , we found issue due to incorrect exception handling.
When Installer install the service but in case of any request , which cause any crash while execution, then service is reflected as running state but stop working.